# Odoo Email Template Customization

Tags: email, odoo

I have Odoo version 10. I want to edit Quotation Email Header and Footer. I want to change

Header Background Color
Footer Background Color
Remove Powered by Odoo

I tried to search every template. but I could not find it.

Your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the Email template form sale

```
<record id="sale.email_template_edi_sale" model="email.template">
...
...
</record>
```

I have customized like this.

```
<record id="sale.email_template_edi_sale" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">Sales Order</field>
            <field name="email_from">${(object.user_id.email and '%s &lt;%s&gt;' % (object.user_id.name, object.user_id.email) or '')|safe}</field>
            <field name="subject">${object.company_id.name} ${object.state in ('draft', 'sent') and 'Quotation' or 'Order'} (Ref ${object.name or 'n/a' })</field>
            <field name="partner_to">${object.partner_invoice_id.id}</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="False"/>
            <field name="email_cc">${object.message_follower_ids.email}</field>
            <field name="lang">${object.partner_id.lang}</field>
            <field name="body_html">
                <![CDATA[
                    <div style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Ubuntu, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-color: #FFF; ">
                        <p>Hi  ${object.prospect_f_name},</p>
                        <p>I appreciate the opportunity to submit a customized proposal for ${object.cmpny_name}. Please see the attached proposal and let me know if you have any questions.</p>
                        <p>Thank you for the opportunity!</p>
                    </div>
                ]]>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to override templates -

The easiest way to override the template is -

```
<template id="module_name.template_id" name="Any Override Template">
    .
    .
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution.

You need to override that  **sale.mail_template_data_notification_email_sale_order** email templates

So just need to copy all code of that template and need to the past into your custom modules.

```
<record id="sale.mail_template_data_notification_email_sale_order" model="mail.template">
<!-- Write same code here and do changes where you want -->
</record>
```

Thanks